# How do I define multiple EF DbContexts that share the same structure so they can use methods interchangeably?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I am using a single database design for 3 different SQL Server locations (production, backup, master).  The design is simple, shown below for the production location:

```
Public Class ProductionDbContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("ProductionDbConnection")
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
        MyBase.New(connectionString)
    End Sub

    Public Property Tables As DbSet(Of Table)     'Table includes a List(Of Topic)
    Public Property Topics As DbSet(Of Topic)     'for direct access to Topics when needed
End Class
```

I have initially coded 3 separate contexts according to what's above, so:

```
Public Class ProductionDbContext
Public Class BackupDbContext
Public Class MasterDbContext
```

When I access these contexts for various operations, I'd like to do something simple like:

```
Dim prodDb As New ProductionDbContext
Dim backupDb As New BackupDbContext
Dim masterDb As New MasterDbContext
Dim topicsList As New List(Of Topic)
LoadData(topicsList, prodDb)     or
LoadData(topicsList, backupDb)   or
LoadData(topicsList, masterDb)
```

And then LoadData is defined as something like (but this doesn't work):

```
Public Sub LoadData(ByRef topicsList As List(Of Topic), localContext As Object)

  Dim thisTopicTable = localContext.Tables.Include("Topics").Where(Function(x) x.Property = "something").SingleOrDefault()
  If thisTopicTable IsNot Nothing Then
    topicsList = thisTopicTable.Topics.ToList()
  End If

End Sub
```

This doesn't work because localContext is not defined properly to have access to the EF methods like .Where and so on.

I know my current design attempt is not correct, but I don't have the experience yet to know how I should have designed things so that the 3 different databases/dbContexts can be treated as similar objects and I don't have to "repeat myself" throughout the code.

There may be a better way to setup the 3 separate databases that I should have used, and that would be great to know (implied question 1), but I would still like to understand more deeply how I use the idea of a Type Object when passing parameters so the object can be coded in the new method the same way as the object being passed in (question 2).  I don't really do a lot of that type of coding; most of my code is very type structured.

I did try to design an intermediate Class that inherits DbContext that could then be inherited by my 3 Classes listed above, but I quickly `lost the pursuit curve' on that.

Comment: If the database schema is the same in all cases then why have three context types defined in the first place? Just use one context type and provide a different connection string for each instance.

Comment: Probably because I didn't think of that! I've never really constructed anything like this, so I didn't see it clearly. Pretty simple, but exactly the reason this forum is so great.  As always, thanks to you personally, JM, for what is always perfect advice.

Comment: WRT passing parameters received in a method as type Object, is there a way to 'reassociate' a Type definition so the variable acts as it would have if it had been defined in the method parameters as that Type? Maybe this is a dumb question.  While this doesn't really apply here because my basic design was poor, I imagine there are times you want to pass items of different types that a method would identify and manipulate as required to perform the same type of operation on those different Types.  Should I ask this in a different SO question?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Now have much simpler code using a single database definition and changing connection string to access.  But may have created issue.  I implemented in Visual Studio w/ migrations; performed a single Enable-Migrations & Add-Migration for the data context. Then executed an Update-Database for each database.  Databases created OK and programmatically work fine, but SSMS is having problems.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463638