# What might cause SSMS queries to reflect incorrect data and how can we clear the problem?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ssms, entity-framework-migrations

I have never experienced this before. SSMS is displaying data tables incorrectly.  SSMS seems to be locked into some previous query result and I don't see how to clear it.

I have an application (MVC) that interfaces to an SQL server. When I run the application's database data delete function, the application shows the table to be empty.  But SSMS still shows data in the table.

If I then run the application's database seed function, the application shows the table to be re-loaded and  I can tell that the data tables are changed because the key index values have incremented.
But, SSMS is still stuck on the older data set.

The only conclusion I can derive is that the SSMS query seems to be stuck.
What causes this, and how can I get past it?

**What I've tried:**

**First**, I ran the SSMS install program and performed a repair, but that didn't solve the problem.  I also uninstalled and re-installed SSMS and that didn't remove the problem.

**Second**, I totally deleted one of the databases from within SSMS, manually.  Then from within Visual Studio's Package Manager Console I ran an Update-Database command to quickly recreate the database with its various tables.  After that, SSMS began showing the proper data again.

**Third**, I've also noticed if I manually delete all records in a table from within SSMS, that seems to also clear the problem.  I say 'seems to also clear', because when I did this operation on a local SQL server, the problem cleared immediately, but on a remote SQL server, the problem didn't clear immediately; but later that problem seems cleared.  The delayed clear of the problem wasn't directly related to the time delay of working a SQL server remotely.

I can do the 2nd and 3rd ideas right now in development; but once in production, that's not a solution.  Plus, it doesn't seem to hold. So, I'd like to find out how to 'reset' the SSMS queries.

**Added after original post:**  In reviewing what is different in the project and what changed recently, this may be connected to Visual Studio migrations, but I don't know how.  In [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61376621) I asked about simplifying my database design to simplify my code.  The result is that I used Visual Studio migrations to create different databases with a common design.  I performed the following EF Migration commands against a single database context:

```
A single: Enable-Migrations
A single: Add-Migration
Multiple: Update-Database (one for each database)
```

It now seems that maybe something in this process could be confusing SSMS along the lines of @Larnu's comment below, but it's beyond me to understand.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't querying the same instance/database/object in SSMS as you are to the other application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I.E., I don't understand how I could be querying a different instance/database/object in SSMS from my application.  I don't doubt what you are saying, I just don't understand it.  When I clear the problem, I'm not making any other changes, but maybe there's something behind the scenes regarding instances/databases/objects that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Do you see any other changes from the application reflected in SSMS? And do you happen to use localdb?

Comment: Yes, when other data tables from the application are updated, the changes are properly reflected in SSMS.  I'm not using localdb, I'm using <pcname>\SQLEXPRESS.  I've added to the post above with another consideration that just came up.